# Service stack server OnReconnect event is not fired when server reconnected successfully

Tags: servicestack

I am working on the serviceStack and react-redux project.
I have to create functionality to detect that the user is connected to the network or not.
For that, I'm using SSE reconnect event to get the response,
what I did is:
I checked the response from the onReconnect event if it gives error then I consider I user is offline.
Which is working fine.
But once a user connected to the OnReconncted event doesn't fire.

Ps: I don't want to use onConnect event as it fires on page refresh also.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you tried using the latest version? My experience with SSE in ServiceStack is that it has been quite flawed and doesnt support all browsers. If it's a bug, I'd make a small web app that simulates the issue and create a post regarding the issue at the ServiceStack forum.

Comment: Hi, @JFM I have solved this problem by customizing the onConect event to detect online and used onReconnect event for offline status.
And this works.